# Passing a class method to another method to call

Tags: ruby

I am writing something as follows

```
module Test
   def self.print(*args)
      p 'something'
      p args
   end
end

def print(*args)
  p "print something"
  p args
end

def method_caller(method_name, *args)
  send(method_name, *args)
end

method_caller(:print, 2) # this works fine
method_caller("print", 2, 3) # this one also
method_caller("Test.print", 2) # this doesn't work
```

Basically, I pass `method_caller` the name of a method and some arguments and then I use the `send` method to actually invoke the method.

I usually pass in the name of the method as a symbol, but how would I deal with `Test.print`?  I imagine at some point I might be passing in objects and having them call their own methods.

The method I would like to invoke could be literally anywhere.

UPDATE:

Trying out each suggestion, the explicit receiver looks like a good way to do it since it's obvious what is happening, but what about christianblais' idea. I changed it to avoid the `eval` call as such

```
def method_caller(method_name, *args)
  if method_name.is_a?(String)
    chain = method_name.split('.')
    obj, method_name = Object.const_get(chain[0...-1].join('.')), chain[-1]
    obj.send(method_name, *args)
  else
    send(method_name, args)
  end
end
```

Which means I can just say `method_caller("Test.print", 2)`, but maybe there are some gotchas...

Comment: You can't call an instance method with that sort of chaining, because the `const_get` won't work if the first part is not a class (`Foo.bar` works, but `foo.bar` won't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, why don't you give your method_caller a receiver argument?

```
def method_caller(receiver, method_name, *args)
  receiver.send(method_name, *args)
end

method_caller(Test, :print, 2)
```

The other calls need to use `self` as the receiver, which is implicit in your current implementation. But finally all this gives you is an incomplete ad hoc reimplementation of `send`, so one really wonders what you are trying to achieve with that.

Comment: Well, it is something like a ruby DSL interpreter-like kind of thing, and I would like to be able to have that interpreter invoke other ruby methods and do things with the return value. I figured using `send` would work out.

Comment: Well, then the explicit receiver is probably a good idea anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There's two things here.

1) Your example won't work, as you're trying to call Test.print with an argument while your method definition doesn't accept one.
*EDIT: Just saw your update. It's now ok. Sorry!*

2) It's evil, but you could always use eval like this :

```
module Test
   def self.print(*args)
     p 'something'
     p args
   end
end

def method_caller(method_name, *args)
  if method_name.is_a?(String)
    chain = method_name.split('.')
    eval(chain[0...-1].join('.')).send(chain.last, args)
  else
    send(method_name, args)
  end
end

method_caller(:print, 2) # this works fine
method_caller("print", 2, 3) # this one also
method_caller("Test.print", 2) # this doesn't work
```

Comment: The chain idea is interesting. I've adapted it to avoid the `eval` call, but not sure how reliable it is.

Answer (score 0):

Is the passing of the method to call as a string a requirement or is it just an idea you had ? A more ruby-ish solution would be to simply pass a block ...

```
method_caller(2) { |*args| Object.print(*args) }
```

Or to give the method object as argument

```
method_caller(Object.method(:print), 2)
```

Which, by the way, works for any object that responds to #call (labmdas, ...)